# How to deploy dotnet core code on Linux machine without stop/start the servcie?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

We have deployed a project which is dotnet core 2.2 to Linux server. When we deploy the code, we have to manually stop/start the service.

Is it possible to deploy the latest code without stop/start service using dotnet commands?

Comment: As far as I understand the application gets compiled to a dll and therefore it needs to be "reloaded" whenever you re deploy it.   What I have done to minimize the steps to deploy is I created a bash script that stops the service, clear the application folder, copy the new files to the application folder and finally starts the service..... So for me publishing became a single command calling the bash... Something like this "sudo ./mypublishscript.sh"

Comment: Simply, no. Once the process is running, it must be stopped to load new code. There is no way around that. If downtime is a concern for you, you should employ containers and an orchestrator like kubernetes. With that, you can have multiple instances of your container running and when you deploy a new image, the orchestrator will intelligently spin down the running containers and then spin up the new container one by one, so that you always have a version running. There's of course *many* other benefits to going this route as well.